# How to get FileInputStream to File in assets folder

Tags: java, android, nio, android-resources

I know how to use the `AssetManager` to read a `File` from the `res/raw` directory with an `InputStream`, but for my special use case I need a `FileInputStream`. The reason I need a `FileInputStream` specifically is because I need to get the `FileChannel` object from it by calling `getChannel()`.

This is the code I have so far, it reads the data (in my case a list of primitives) from a `File`:

```
public static int[] loadByMappedBuffer(Context context, String filename) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(filename);
    FileChannel ch = fis.getChannel();

    MappedByteBuffer mbuff = ch.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, ch.size());
    IntBuffer ibuff = mbuff.asIntBuffer();

    int[] array = new int[ibuff.limit()];
    ibuff.get(array);

    fis.close();
    ch.close();

    return array;
}
```

I had tried to create `File` from an `Uri`, but that just results in a `FileNotFoundException`:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.empty/raw/file");
File file = new File(uri.getPath());
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Is there a way I can get a `FileInputStream` to a `File` in the `res/raw` directory?

Comment: I think your URL is the problem.And you should add from the assets directory.

Comment: So all you need is to read file contents as int array? Am I correct?

Comment: @Ayzen yes, but I need to make it fast, method, that I gave reads 80K*4 bytes and transform it to int array by 6-7 ms on my PC

Comment: @KristyWelsh I also had tried `Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.empty/" + R.raw.file);`

Comment: Try this: InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(YOUR_FILE_NAME)

Comment: @KristyWelsh I need `FileInputStream` and I don't work with DB, I'm working with text file

Comment: @MichaelHerasimov - I updated my comment - and you just need to be able to read from the file, right?

Comment: @KristyWelsh but it still `InputStream`

Comment: FileInputStream myfileInput = getResources().getAssets().open(FILE_NAME); Will work.

Comment: @KristyWelsh I'm "just" need to be able transform this code for Android

Comment: @MichaelHerasimov ??

Comment: @KristyWelsh ok, I will try it

Comment: @KristyWelsh I mean I had gave code that reads file from `files` directory and I need to read file by this method from `raw` directory

Comment: @KristyWelsh `open` method returns `InputStream`

Comment: getResources().getAssets().open() doesn't return FileInputStream. It returns AssetInputStream.

Comment: @Ayzen and there are a way to get `FileInputStream` from `AssetInputStream`?

Comment: It seems the only way to read your data is using InputStream...

Comment: @ChrisStratton but how to deal wiyh `nio` when I have `InputStream`?

Comment: You don't need to for this.  Focus on the problem, which appears to be reading an array of ints from an InputStream.  You don't need a MappedByteBuffer for that.

Comment: Related problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395744/filechannel-returns-wrong-file-size-of-file-in-assets-folder

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can get a `FileInputStream` to a resource in your assets like this:

```
AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd(fileName);
FileInputStream stream = fileDescriptor.createInputStream();
```

The `fileName` you supply to `openFd()`  should be the relative path to the asset, the same `fileName` you would supply to `open()`.

Alternatively you can also create the `FileInputStream` like this:

```
AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd(fileName);  
FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();  
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor);
```

Comment: You can use `getAssets()` to get assetManager

Answer (score 1):

small tweeking in "@Xaver Kapeller" answer:
if u don't get "assetManager" use "ctx.getAssets()" instead;

```
AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = ctx.getAssets().openFd(fileName);  
FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();  
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor);
```