# FileChannel returns wrong file size of file in assets folder

Tags: java, android, assets, fileinputstream

I am trying to read a `File` from the raw folder in my assets using a `FileInputStream`.

This is how I create the `FileInputStream`:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd(fileName);
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
```

After that I am trying to read the data from the `File` like this:

```
FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();

MappedByteBuffer mappedByteBuffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fileChannel.size());
IntBuffer intBuffer = mappedByteBuffer.asIntBuffer();

int[] array = new int[intBuffer.limit()];
intBuffer.get(array);

inputStream.close();
fileChannel.close();
```

But this does not work. For some reason `fileChannel.size()` returns a huge number. I have a test file which is exactly 13 bytes long, but `fileChannel.size()` returns 1126498! And additionally if I ignore the size and just start reading the returned bytes don't match my test file at all!

So what is going on here? And is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Why would you go to all that trouble to read 13 bytes? Why not just use the FileInputStream? There's more source code, and byte code, than there are bytes in the file.

Comment: @EJP I need to read 80K ints from file in my application that's why I need nio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your app is compiled all resources are packaged together into what is essentially one big `File`. To get just the data of the one `File` you want to read you have to use `getStartOffset()` and `getDeclaredLength()` of the `AssetFileDescriptor`. From the [**documentation**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor.html):

> - `getStartOffset()`: Returns the byte offset where this asset entry's data starts.
> - `getDeclaredLength()`: Return the actual number of bytes that were declared when the AssetFileDescriptor was constructed. Will be
>     [UNKNOWN_LENGTH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor.html#UNKNOWN_LENGTH) if the length was not declared, meaning data should be
>     read to the end of the file.

---

So instead of just reading the whole `File` from start to finish you just need to read the data starting at the index returned by `getStartOffset()` and you need to read as many bytes as are returned by `getDeclaredLength()`. Try something like this:

```
long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
MappedByteBuffer mappedByteBuffer = fileChannel.map(
        FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 
        startOffset, 
        declaredLength);
```

If you want to account for the case in which `getDeclaredLength()` returns `UNKNOWN_LENGTH` you can just do this:

```
if(declaredLength == AssetFileDescriptor.UNKNOWN_LENGTH) {
    declaredLength = fileChannel.size() - startOffset;
}
```