# Android Read XML File

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just want to read a simple xml-File with Android Studio.

```
new File("Questions.xml");
```

Used in "MainActivity"

Where do I have to put the xml-File in my project?
This is the File-Structure:

[image: link to filestructure image]

Comment: Put it in the `assets` folder, not the packages for the Java code

Comment: Then see [read that file from assets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354120/how-to-get-fileinputstream-to-file-in-assets-folder)